# Escape some characters in a echo - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make an while who shows something like an json file.
This is the JSON file that I want to imitate, but with PHP and MYSQL

```
{
        "success": 1,
        "result": [
                {
                        "id": "293",
                        "title": "This is warning class event",
                        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
                        "class": "event-warning",
                        "start": "1362938400000",
                        "end":   "1363197686300"
                },
                {
                        "id": "294",
                        "title": "This is information class ",
                        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
                        "class": "event-info",
                        "start": "1363111200000",
                        "end":   "1363284086400"
                },
                {
                        "id": "297",
                        "title": "This is success event",
                        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
                        "class": "event-success",
                        "start": "1363284000000",
                        "end":   "1363284086400"
                }
```

Then I continues to make the while

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");

    mysql_select_db("db",$link) OR DIE ("Error: No es posible establecer la conexión");

    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    $eventos= mysql_query("SELECT * from eventos",$link);

    echo ("{'success': 1, 'result': [");

    while($matrizu=mysql_fetch_array($eventos))
    {


        $evento=$matrizu["id"];
        $nombre=$matrizu["name"];
        $clase=$matrizu["categoria"];
        $inicio=$matrizu["datetime"];
        $final=$matrizu["end"];

        echo ('"{"  
                "id": ".$evento.",
                "title": ".$nombre.",
                "url": "http://www.example.com",
                "class": ".$clase.",
                "start": ".$inicio.",
                "end": ".$final."

            "}",');
     }

    echo("        
        ]
}");
```

But I can't escape the characters for do it seems like the JSON file.
This is for this [Bootstrap calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar).

And the author of that Calendar, says, that I have to do something like this:

```
<?php
$db    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$start = $_REQUEST['from'] / 1000;
$end   = $_REQUEST['to'] / 1000;
$sql   = sprintf('SELECT * FROM events WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN %s and %s',
    $db->quote(date('Y-m-d', $start)), $db->quote(date('Y-m-d', $end)))

$out = array()
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $out[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'title' => $row->name,
        'url' => Helper::url($row->id),
        'start' => strtotime($row->datetime) . '000'
    );
}

echo json_encode($out);
exit;
```

And is not working either

Comment: `And isn't work too!` isn't a useful error description. What happens or doesn't? We *really* need more details to be able to help you.

Comment: Definetly go with the second solution using json_encode(). But as said, proide a bit more info the actual error.

Comment: what does `json_encode($out);` output

Answer (score 0):

The second option you're showing is the way to go, there's absolutely no point in trying to manually create correctly formatted/escaped JSON when there is an inbuilt PHP function to generate it. Structurally, you need to start your array with the `success` and `result` keys, then push your database results to the `result` key:

```
$out = array(
    'success' => 1,
    'result' => array()
);
```

Now you easily get your values and push them to the `result` key:

```
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $out['result'][] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['name'],
        'url' => Helper::url($row['id']), // up to you whether this is correct here...
        'class' => $row['categoria']
        'start' => $row['datetime'],
        'end' => $row['end']
    );
}
```

That's just taking your original attempt and plugging the variables into the second example - [here's the PDO query manual FYI](https://www.php.net/pdo.query). As a side note, you shouldn't have a field in your table named `datetime` - while it's not a reserved word, it's also not good practice as it's a column type.

Now you just go:

```
echo json_encode($out);
```

... and you should have the JSON you're after.